# Merge JSON records using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a huge json file as follows,

```
{"id": "KA88457","name": "Steven", "phone":"+6590876589"},
{"id": "KA88457", "fax": ["+6563323248"], "email":"steve@alexandra.com"}
```

I need to merge the two and obtain the desired result as

```
{"id": "KA88457",
 "name": "Steven", 
 "phone":"+6590876589", 
 "fax":["+6563323248"], 
 "email":"steve@alexandra.com"}
```

I checked online but I was able to find only merging two json files in python. Can you please help to in merging these type of records using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionaries have a `.update()` method, which can also be used for your situation. It is used to update the original dict to include the changes or addition from the second dict.

```
first_dict={"id": "KA88457","name": "Steven", "phone":"+6590876589"}
second_dict={"id": "KA88457", "fax": ["+6563323248"], "email":"steve@alexandra.com"}
first_dict.update(second_dict)
print(first_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 'KA88457', 'name': 'Steven', 'phone': '+6590876589', 'fax': ['+6563323248'], 'email': 'steve@alexandra.com'}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a doubt. 1. The file is very big. How will I be able to know first_dict has to append with second_dict ? May be I use loop to check if it has similar id, it has to append and remove duplicates. Is there any other solution ? 2. How can I assign those each dictionary to a new variable like first_dict and second_dict ? Sorry to bother with silly questions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to convert the strings from json to a python dictionary object (see json module) you can 'merge' them in the way you describe, with the following:

```
objOne = {"id": "KA88457","name": "Steven", "phone":"+6590876589"}
objTwo = {"id": "KA88457", "fax": ["+6563323248"], "email":"steve@alexandra.com"}

for key in objOne:
    objTwo[key] = objOne[key]
```

This should take all the properties of objOne and add them to objTwo.

Comment: So you mean, I have to convert them to strings and then use json module called merge ? Also the file size is too huge.  I'm new to python. So, I'm confused on how to proceed.

Comment: The above is already a dictionary right ? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Those are dictionary objects. But if you read them in from a file, they'll come in as strings, and you'll need to parse them into a dictionary object.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm reading them from a file. So which means i need to parse them. I shall give a try.